# Crawling PDF file using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, pdf, casperjs

I am trying to crawl the content of a PDF file which is made using pdf.js
[Example](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)

The problem is some of the DOM elements are showing in FireBug but not in page source, so whenever I try to crawl, I get blank pdf page.

I tried same thing with NightWatchJs and it worked but for some specific purpose I want to stick with CasperJS.

Here is my code

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0  poi poi poi (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22',
    contentType: 'application/pdf',
    viewportSize: {
        width:2000,
        height:1000
    },
    pageSettings: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        loadImages: true,
        loadPlugins: true
    }
});

var fs = require('fs');

casper.start('https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html', function() {

     this.waitForSelector("#pageContainer1", function check() {
          var pdfContent = this.getPageContent();
          fs.write( '/var/www/caspersJS/pdf_check.html', pdfContent, 'w+' );

          this.capture('/var/www/caspersJS/pdf_check.png', {
                top:0,
                left:0,
                height:2368,
                width:2024,
                format: 'png',
                quality: 100
          });
     }, function then() {
          var pdfContent = this.getPageContent();
          fs.write( '/var/www/caspersJS/pdf_then.html', pdfContent, 'w+' );

          this.capture('/var/www/caspersJS/pdf_then.png', {
                top:0,
                left:0,
                height:2368,
                width:2024,
                format: 'png',
                quality: 100
          });
     }, 60000);
});
casper.run();
```

Comment: Hi Artjom B. 

If you open [link](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)  you will see pdf has content  "Trace-based Just-in-Time Type Specialization for Dynamic". I want to crawl that content.

Comment: If you just need a text content, you don't have to use casper or phantom, just use an API to get text content. See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/getinfo.js

Comment: Hi Artjom.. If you see my script , I am waiting for 60 seconds for that id to be loaded but the problem is pdf is not loading only. I confirmed that by capture screen.

Comment: Hi Async5.. I will give it a try tonight.

Comment: No, you're waiting until `#pageContainer1` detected with a *maximum* wait timeout of 60 seconds.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You haven't fully waited until the page (and PDF) is loaded. `#pageContainer1` is the container for the first page, but it's possible that the container exists, but its contents are not yet created.

`casper.waitForSelector(selector, then, onTimeout, timeout)` will wait until `selector` is available in the DOM and then execute the `then` callback. If it hasn't found `selector` after `timeout` milliseconds of waiting, it will execute `onTimeout`.

You can either devise a better selector that can show you whether the pages are loaded or you can wait a static amount of time:

```
this.waitForSelector("#pageContainer1")
    .wait(5000, function() {
        var pdfContent = this.getPageContent();
        fs.write( 'pdf_check.html', pdfContent, 'w+' );

        this.capture('pdf_check.png');
    });
```

Comment: Still no luck. I even tried changing wait time to 20000 but still getting following error.

[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/4: done in 2506ms.
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.

Comment: It works for me with PhantomJS 2.1.1. Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: My Phantomjs version is 1.9.0

I tried adding "remote.message", "page.error", "resource.error", "page.initialized" but still no luck. I will upgrade phantomjs and try again.

Comment: Worked after I upgraded phantomjs to 2.1. Thanks a lot Artjom B.

Comment: Artjom B : when i open pdf pageContainer1 id does not exist id is page1 with both id i am getting error [error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this post when I am doing research about a similar problem. You have probably moved on to something else. But I just want to add a little bit for people that are looking into these problems.

As far as I know, each pages content viewed in pdf.js is only loaded when you scroll to/near its position. So be sure to add scrolls to your script if you want information not just on page 1. And if you are looking forward to get the whole file. You can actually download it with PDFView.download(); which is a provided function in pdf.js as long as you can view the whole pdf.